# Как повернуть 2добъект к цели?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Моя цель - поворачивать 2дgameobject в сторону другого 2dgameobject(target).

я нашел следующий код:

```css
Quaternion rawRoation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,
            Quaternion.LookRotation(Player.GetComponent<Transform>().position - transform.position),
            10*Time.deltaTime);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rawRoation.eulerAngles.z);
```

Но тут беда, если положение цели по оси x меньше(левее) нашего объекта, то поворот работает неправильно, похоже на инверсию. Как решить эту проблему, переписать код?

[image: Удачный поворот]
[image: неудачный поворот]

p.s. этот метод находится в Update()

Answer (score 0):

Кинули ответ на основной версии.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    Vector3 targetDir = target.position - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(targetDir.y, targetDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    Quaternion q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, q, Time.deltaTime * 10);
}
```